# Geo Sorting Post

Tags: geo-data

I wanna sort all post by GEO Location.Can you provide me an idea on how can I do that.

When user submit a post, should I ask for a location as a tag but at the same time I wanna have tags to work as tags. Also Categories needs to be work as category. I am not sure how can I sort them.

However, there will be address as a custom field associate to each post.

Please guide me to a way to have this done or redirect me to a plugin that works.

Regards,

Comment: Custom Fields/Post Meta Data is what you're looking for. You could then query by meta_key/meta_value.

Comment: Just like what kaiser said. Maybe 2 meta value, 'latitude' & 'longitude', so you can sort it using '<' or '>' operator

Comment: I already have two custom field containing latitude and longitude. but how do i make use of it ?

Comment: Use the `query_posts()` function with [`meta_key` & `order` parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Any progress? Tried any geo location plugins?

Comment: did not find any plugin yet that does the work...

Comment: Did you try what @rilwis said?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a plugin? I just released not long ago http://geomywp.com it basically does what you want. If you want to do it yourself so this is how I did it:
The plugin adds address custom fields (as meta boxes) to your post type. When post is being saved the address being converted to lat/long using google API and the data being saved in a custom table. This way you create a database table for your posts with lat/long. 
When a user want to search your site Using the search form he can enter any address in the  input field and choose radius value from drop down menu. The address again , being converted to lat/long and using custom SQL query you can check the user's address against each lat/long in the custom database's table. Then you can output posts within the given radius and ordered them by the distance from the address.

Comment: sure, I will look into it. Looks good tho.

Comment: thank you. i would love to get any feedback if you get to use it. it is a new release so i'd like to know if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't solved this, I wrote a plugin a couple days ago that creates metaboxes for storing location data on selected post types (you choose which types via an interface). It also provides an extended WP_Query, that does distance searches and returns posts as well as distance, location, lat, and long.

https://github.com/fyaconiello/wp-geo-posts

give it a go, let me know what you think.